# Persistent mysql data from docker container

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, persistence

How can I persist data from my mysql container? I'd really like to mount /var/lib/mysql from the container to the host machine. This indeed creates the directory, but when I create data, stop my application, and start a new one with the mounted directory, nothing is there. I've messed around with giving the directory all permissions and changing the user and group to root but nothing seems to work. I keep seeing people saying to use a data container, but I don't see how that can work with Amazon ec2 container service (ECS), considering each time I stop and start a task it would create a new data container rather than use an existing one. Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply run your containers with something like this:

```
docker run -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -t -i <container_id> <command>
```

You can keep your host /var/lib/mysql and mount it to each one of the containers.  Now this is not going to work with EC2 Container service unless all of your servers that you use for containers map to a common /var/lib/mysql (Perhaps nfs mounted from a master EC2 instance)

[AWS EFS](http://aws.amazon.com/efs/) is going to be great for this once it becomes widely available.